# Angular ngResource "CartResource.get is not a function!"

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

In my app, I define a cart resource

```
.factory('CartResource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/Cart/:id');
    });
```

on the module.  In my logincontroller,

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('ShoppingCart')
        .controller('loginController', ['CartResource','cart', loginController]);

    function loginController(CartResource, cart) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.model = cart.model;
        vm.login = login;

        function login(username, password) {
            CartResource.get({ username: username, password: password }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
        }
    };
}());
```

I am injecting the CartResource and trying to get a user object by passing a username and password.  However, whenever I call `login()`, it says that `CartResource.get` is not a function.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm doing almost this exact same thing in another application but it doesn't seem to work here. Is there something wrong with the order in which I include my script files in my `index.html`?

```
<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.config.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/services/Cart.resource.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems like just a Typo. Explicit annotation list (`'CartResource','cart'`) and argument list of the constructor (`loginController(cart, CartResource) `) must be in the same order, in your case they are reversed

Comment: Hmm, I fixed the order, but that actually didn't fix it.  I'm still getting `CartResource.get is not a function`.  I updated the OP to have the fixed order

Comment: Log `CartResource` - what's it show?

Comment: [Here is a Fork of your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/1zwXhn?p=preview), but without the `car` injection since we don't known what is. And it works just fine

Comment: Hm, you're right.  Taking out the reference to cart does seem to make it work.  I also tried putting cart last  and that also seemed to fix it.  Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow changing the order of the dependencies seemed to fix it.  Sadly I don't have anything more specific to add.